# How to zoom in and out the active window using a scrollbar in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub ScrollBar1_Change()
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = ScrollBar1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm1_Initialize()
 With ScrollBar1
    .Min = 10
    .Max = 400
    .SmallChange = 1
    .LargeChange = 10
 End With
End Sub
```

I used the above code but get this run time error:

> error 1004(unable to set the zoom property of the window class)

Comment: Weird task, I guess I don't understand your case. UserForm1? Do you know about Ctrl-Scrollwheel?

Answer (score 1):

Move the code to the `Activate` event instead of the `Initialize` event so that it updates the initial value properly. The error is because the initial value is still 1 otherwise, and you can't zoom below 10%.

Comment: it will also work if you set the min and max values of the ScrollBar in the IDE and then run the code.

Comment: @sous2817 Well yes - I assumed there was a reason for not doing it at design time. ;)

Comment: fair enough.  I was just giving an alternate way to make the original code work, but I didn't think it warranted a separate answer.  Wasn't meant to come across as a knock on your answer.

Comment: @sous2817 I wasn't offended at all - sorry, I hoped the smilie would make that clear. :-)

Comment: yep, we're on the same page :)

Comment: Adjusted the min & max values of the scrollbar in the IDE. It worked.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the the zoom needing to be above 10. Do something like this.

```
Private Sub ScrollBar1_Change()
    Dim i As Integer

    i = ScrollBar1.Value
    If i <= 10 Then
        i = 10
    End If

    ActiveWindow.Zoom = i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also post this part:

```
With ScrollBar1
    .Min = 10
    .Max = 400
    .SmallChange = 1
    .LargeChange = 10
 End With
```

In the same block as:

```
ActiveWindow.Zoom = ScrollBar1.Value
```

So it looks like this:

```
Private Sub ScrollBar1_Change()
ActiveWindow.Zoom = ScrollBar1.Value
With ScrollBar1
    .Min = 10
    .Max = 400
    .SmallChange = 1
    .LargeChange = 10
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Without adding the min max values at the design time,just adjusted those values in the scrollbar IDE and it worked.